# EC2 bitnami rubystack extremely slow

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running a single rails application on bitnami RubyStack 3.2.7-0 (rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3) on a micro instance.

The application is pretty simple, users can log in, upload some files, change their account settings, and that is pretty much it.

my concern is that simplest operations are taking extremely long to respond e.g. log-in takes about two minutes to respond (and all it has to do is fetch corresponding user from db and verify the password).

use-cases which involve sending emails (e.g. forgot password) take even longer but I guess that is because it takes some time to connect to gmail's smtp server (that's what I am using to send emails).

any ideas why it's so slow? should I upgrade instance's size?

Comment: I'll add that I upgraded from Micro to Medium instance, which improved the speed but just a little bit. so something is wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 1.9.3 with patches from falcon:
1. for speed up load time
2. for decrease memory for hash
(both summarized here https://gist.github.com/1688857?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email)
3. backport garbage collector from ruby 2.0 https://gist.github.com/1687289